# Configure Static IP from server side requests from an AWS Amplify-hosted website

Tags: amazon-web-services, reverse-proxy, aws-amplify, server-side-rendering, static-ip-address

I have to make requests to an application that has a Whitelist IP, so I have to ensure my IP of my website will be always the same, but AWS Amplify doesn't offer configurations about this. What can I do?

There are other questions related in SOF but they don't have answers.

There aren't configurations about it in the AWS Amplify console, I don't even know if this is possible with additional configurations. So, are there alternatives for requesting data with a static IP?

My possible solution would be to mount a reverse proxy, in EC2 and allocate an elastic IP, but it could be possible there are better options.

Currently, I have registered four IPs that belong to the DNS Provider that AWS gave me, it works, but it is a possible security risk.